# Core Plot crashes when i drag/scroll

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a graph with several columns and several barcharts that are overlayed.  originally, this was causing an out of memory even though it only showed 2MB of usage in Xcode instruments.

now, it crashes without any memory notice when i try to drag/scroll.

i traced this down to this method in CPTGraphHostingView.  after exiting this method, it crashes.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint pointOfTouch = [[[event touchesForView:self] anyObject] locationInView:self];
    if (!collapsesLayers) {
        pointOfTouch = [self.layer convertPoint:pointOfTouch toLayer:hostedGraph];
    } else {
        pointOfTouch.y = self.frame.size.height - pointOfTouch.y;
    }
    [hostedGraph pointingDeviceUpEvent:event atPoint:pointOfTouch];
}
```

if  i reduce the number of barcharts, it will let me drag some, but eventually it will crash.

anyone else having similiar issues ?

btw this is the latest code (11/5/2011).

Comment: How many bar plots are in your graph? Can you post the error message and/or stack trace from the crash?

Comment: There are 42 bar charts.  There is no error message or stack trace at all. the screen goes black with a spinner and goes back to the device lock screen.

Comment: I put breakpoints all around the touch code in CPTGraphHostingView to see if there is a particular crash point.  it only crashes after touchesEnded returns.  it seems that something is happening within the dragging - maybe some buffer overflow - that is causing a hard crash.  i can't be sure of this since it doesn't crash in the simulator.

Comment: 42 instances of `CPTBarPlot` in one graph? Is `collapsesLayers` YES or NO? If NO, try setting it to YES to conserve RAM on the graphics hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collapsesLayers = YES` fixes the issue - thanks Eric.

FYI this is a business graph which shows number of products for a given month, this is why the number of Bar Charts is so high.  If there is a different way to do this, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `collapsesLayers = YES` if you are making multiple charts from single `CPTGraphHostingView`, instead use something like this to prevent from memory crashing issue in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method for table view:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GraphCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"GraphCell"];
}
for (id v in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[CPTGraphHostingView class]])
    {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = NO;
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.hostView];



/*     Configure Graph           */
// 1 - Create the graph
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)];
graph.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
//1].CGColor;
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
```